# Preferences in Android earlier than 3.0

Tags: java, android, preferences

I have the problem, that SharedPreferences with FragmentManager won't work in Android below 3.0.
I always get this error:

`java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: mypackage.Settings.getFragmentManager`

How can I provide preferences for both: below and above 3.0?

I searched alot and found different solutions but nothing worked for me :/ Can anyone give me a good step by sep explination?

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below 3.0, you should use support library and call getSupportFragmentManager()